# How can I remove part of an string on the re.search result?

Tags: python

```
text = urllib.urlopen('www.text.com').read()
frase = re.search("your text here(.*)", text).group()
```

With these code, I get the result as "your text here mister"...

How can I remove the your text here from the result, staying only with the "mister" part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the number of the group (= thing between parenthesis in the regex) you want to receive in the call to [`group()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group):

```
frase = re.search(...).group(1)
```

Comment: and if I get something before the "mister", like, "mister wrong"... how do I remove the "wrong" ?

Comment: @Shady: Edit the regular expression so that it matches (only) the correct text and put the parenthesis around the part you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

don't need regex

```
text = urllib.urlopen('www.text.com').read()
print ''.join( text.split("your text here")[1:] )
```

Comment: good, it works... but it transform string as list... how can I convert back?

Comment: to convert list back to string, use join().